# RadRails trial expired - any free options for Rails in Eclipse?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, eclipse, ide

I installed RadRails a while back and uninstalled it after it said that my trial had expired.

Is it correct that this is the only option for Rails development in Eclipse?

And is there any other - free - option for Eclipse? (I tried "Ruby RDT" but it doesn't offer any Rails support, just basic Ruby editing.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the full [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/), and after it says the Professional trial is over, you can continue using the Community Edition mode.

Doesn't seem to be a way to just get the Community Edition by itself, but it'll just ask you to close and restart Eclipse after 30 days.

Answer (score 1):

Try Aptana IDE - it is Eclipse based and totally free. Also as much as I know its Rails support is bases on Rad Rails eclipse plugin.

BTW, I'm using NetBeans 6.5.1 for Rails and I've already convinced everybody is my office that it is better than Aptana :)

Comment: Yes, Netbeans is definitely the best IDE for Ruby/Rails that I've seen. Unfortunately I need to do a project that requires me to use a couple of other tools that are only available for Eclipse :(

Comment: I tried Netbeans a while back and it was a bigger memory pig than even Aptana. Is it better now?

Comment: It is definitely better now - no more unexpected crashes, debugger is awesome, code navigation rocks, etc! I just switched to version 6.7 RC1 and its good so far.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Eclipse for a while for Rails development, based on RDT plus mods described in the following article:

www.napcs.com/howto/railsonwindows.html